# Unusual power management following fresh reinstall of 16.10

Tags: suspend, power-management, shutdown, 16.10

I am searching for some help. I have done a fresh reinstall of 16.10 on a lenovo thinkpad e520 laptop. Since the install I have noticed 2 funny things.

1. The "Shutdown" button from the top right menu calls the same log out/lock dialog as the log out button.
   Searching for 'Shutdown' from the dash results in the same behaviour. That is, there is no way to shutdown the laptop form the gui.
   The shutdown command works correctly from the terminal. The power button executes an immediate shutdown, not calling up any dialog.
2. From the Power menu, I have selected 'do nothing' upon closing the lid for both battery and ac power.
   Despite this, the laptop still suspends.
   I am not sure if the two are related, nor how I can go about fixing this.
   Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks very much.
   Justin.

Comment: Smells like a bug. Have you fully updated the system already?

Comment: Yes, the system is up to date. Apt-get is happy. Thanks for the suggestion. Beginning to think that a reinstall might be required, though it is a lot of work to end up were I am again.

Comment: Note that the second problem has been answered, and thus is no longer a problem. I am still not sure what to do about part one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's causing the first problem but for your second one you can type:

```
gksu gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Look for these two lines and change them to look like this:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
```

These should be the defaults anyway but remove the `#` in front of them if it's there. Save the file and reboot.

From now on when you close the lid hopefully it doesn't suspend as you desire. If not we have to look elsewhere....

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to help. It has done the trick. Lid behaviour is now as desired.